# NoMethodError While Doing Hartl's RailsTutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a `NoMethodError` while working through Hartl's Rails Tutorial. This error started showing up in chapter 11. Not sure where to track the problem back to. This is the error message:

```
NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home undefined method `signed_in?' for #<StaticPagesController:0x007fa1b44a4ab8>

Rails.root: /Users/dbk/projects/apster

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
```

And here's the code from my StaticPagesController:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        if signed_in?
            @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
            @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
    end

end
```

Here's my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Here's my sessions helper file:

```
    module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)    
  end

  def sign_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end


    def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

Comment: Somewhere in your Application Controller, you should have defined this method (`def signed_in?...`).  Can you provide your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file?

Comment: Look for occurences of `signed_in?` in the tutorial. You messed up with its definition in one way or another.

Comment: Ah, so it must be defined in your `SessionsHelper`.  Do you see it there? (`app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb`)

Comment: Is the issue that in the sessions helper it's defined as "sign_in" as opposed to "signed_in"?

Comment: No, `sign_in` is a separate method that signs in the user.  `signed_in?` is a boolean method that checks whether the user is currently signed in (note that Ruby methods are supposed to read like English.  'sign in' is an action, while 'signed in? is a question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NoMethodError` means exactly that. A method that does not exist, or is not loaded, was called. This happens because you called your method `logged_in?` in `SessionsHelper`.

```
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

But you are calling `signed_in?` in `StaticPagesController`, which does not exist, and hence the error.

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. So I fixed that in the SessionsHelper. But now I'm getting this error - undefined method `feed' for #<User:0x007fa1b842ad68>

    else
        match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
      end
    end

Comment: You're welcome. That's a different error, and it requires we look at different parts of your code. It's hard to say what the problem is without a closer look. You should post another question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks, again.